# How do to retrieve all pages when consuming a REST API in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, http, spring-boot

I am using the following code to consume a GET call in Spring Boot and I am storing the result as a JSON. However, I am able to retrieve only 100 records, which is the default page size of the API. How do I retrieve the entire data (all the pages)?

```
            public static void getData(String baseDir, String baseURI, String headerFieldName, String headerFieldValue) {


                        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
                        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
                        headers.add(headerFieldName, headerFieldValue);
                        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
                        String data = restTemplate.exchange(baseURI +  HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class).getBody();
                        dataWriter(data, baseDir + File.separator + File.separator + ".json");
            }

            private static void dataWriter(final String data, final String filePath)
                {

                    try {
                        Files.write(Paths.get(filePath), data.getBytes());
                    }
                    catch (final IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
```

Where:

baseURI = www.xxxxxx.com/records

headerFieldName is set to "Authorization" and headerFieldValue contains the access token.

The data set contains about 18000 records.

After caling the API I get the following response where count is the number of records in the response.

```
            {
                "count": 18000,
                "data": [{
                    "id": "96d8-3024739ed555",
                    .....
                    .....
                },
                {
                    "id": "8595-0a27472aef0e",
                    .....
                    .....
                }
                ...
                ....
                ]
            }
```

Is there a way where I can fetch only the "count" field only? Which I can then use to loop and get all the records from "data".

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try printing the String `data` before you write it to `dataWriter(...)`? Also please share the method `dataWriter(...)`

Comment: How many values do you get when sending the request via the browser? Also, try adding query params `page=1,2,3...` to the URI

Comment: Quick update: I get 100 values when I send it via browser by default, however @MaruthiAdithya when I send the request with the limit set to "count" I get all the records. I have corrected the question now
e.g. /records?limit=18000

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya: How will he know if that number does change in the future?

Comment: @NicholasK updated the question with dataWriter

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya yes, I don't know the number of pages also the number of records can change in future which might increase or decrease the page count

Comment: @Sambhav : Have you tried printing the value of `data` before writing to `dataWriter(...)`?

Comment: @Sambhav Are you sure that you don't get the page number anywhere?

Comment: @NicholasK, yes it contains the same values which are written to the file by DataWriter

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya nope, no info on page number

Comment: Are you sure you are accessing the same url via rest client and your code?

Comment: @NicholasK Yes!

Comment: In your comment, '*when I send the request with the limit set to "count" I get all the records.*'-- do you mean via rest client or code? Also where are you setting this?

Comment: @NicholasK Its via rest client, I am trying to figure out how to I fetch only the "count" part directly from the response body via RestTemplate so that I can use that in my code.

Comment: You'll need to use some sort of regex for that then.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured a workaround by using JsonPath to get the "count".

```
             final String data = restTemplate.exchange(baseURI + api + "?limit=0", HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class).getBody();
             final int count = JsonPath.read(data, "$.count");
```

Thanks, Everyone!